# Renaming Voice memos

Tags: voice-memo

I have several voice memos on my MacBook (OSX 12.7.3).  They have strange computer-generated names eg 2023-08-16T06:57:55Z

When I highlight these to give them a meaningful name, the new name appears to be accepted and then reverts to the computer-generated version.

How can I deal with this please?